# How to get the key(id) of the binded checkListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am have a Windows Forms application and also using SQL to get the data from my db. I have a binded checkListBox in my Windows Forms application and I would like to get the primary key (the value) of **all the checked Items** in my checkListBox. What I realize is in combo box, they have a build in method 'selectedValue' I am wondering if we can do the same thing in checkListBox by looping through the checkedItems in checkListBox and get its value

Let say in my db table, I have:

```
EmployeeId    Employee Name
1                 Jimmy
2                 Pam
3                 Bob
4                 Kobe
```

My binded checkListBox showed something like

```
[x]Jimmy
[x]Pam
[]Bob
[]Kobe
```

Can I get the checkedItem item's id by using sql query. Now let say Jimmy and Pam is checked and I want to get their employeeId. I am not sure how to do it. Help will be appreciated.

```
select * from employee_table where employeeId = '"+checkListBox.SelectedValue+"'
```

or

```
foreach(var item = item.CheckedItems{
     select * from employee_table where employeeId = '"items"';
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code that **populates** the list box.

Comment: I strongly believe you already have EmployeeID with you, and you don't need to fire any query for that. Just see the code where you filled the checkliistbox, at that time you are pulling EmployeeID and name both. You are binding ID and Name to CheckListbox and you are getting name by selectedvalue property. Why don't u try SelectedItem to get the ID's..

Comment: Moreover I feel, you should understand the flow, rather jumping on coding.. So spend sometime on paper to understand the flow, and get familiar with WindowsApplication controls.

Comment: @DragonBorn I saw your other question about this topic has been answered. You can kindly accept my answer here, since it is a good answer for times when you are not using `DataTable` :) This way it will be more useful for other users in future:)

Comment: @RezaAghaei will do :)

Comment: @DragonBorn Thank you so much:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to go  to database again to retrieve Id of your items.

You can create a class for items that contains an `Id` and a `Name` property and override `ToString` method to return the string that you want to show in `CheckedListBox`:

```
public class ItemModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Then when loading data, you can select the output and shape it to `ItemModel` and then add these `ItemModel`s to CheckedListBox:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var db = new TestDBEntities();

    //Select items that you need and shape it to ItemModel
    var list = db.Categories.Select(x => new ItemModel
                    {
                        Id = x.Id,
                        Name = x.Name
                    })
                    .ToList();

    //We cast the list to object[] because AddRange method accept object[]
    this.checkedListBox1.Items.AddRange(list.Cast<object>().ToArray());
}
```

Then when you need to know `Id` of checked items, you can simply cast each checked item to `ItemModel` an use its `Id` property:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Cast<ItemModel>()
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(item =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Id:{0}, Name:{1}", item.Id, item.Name));
        });
}
```

**Note:**

If you use another method to connect to database, you can simply change this code to satisfy your requirements, for example this code uses `ADO.Net` objects to shape data to `ItemModel`:

```
private void CheckedListBoxSample_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var connection = @"data source=(localdb)\v11.0;initial catalog=TestDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";
    var command = "SELECT Id, Name From Categories";
    var dataAdapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(command, connection);
    var table = new DataTable();
    dataAdapter.Fill(table);

    var list = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
        .Select(row => new ItemModel
        {
            Id = row.Field<int>("Id"),
            Name = row.Field<string>("Name")
        })
        .ToList();

    this.checkedListBox1.Items.AddRange(list.Cast<object>().ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines might help you.
Basically what it does, is that it builds a parameterized query, and then adds all the selected items using [SqlParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx). Then using the reader, you are able to parse each returned record. The code below will probably need some modifications for you to use it, but should help you getting started.

Although I would strongly suggest using an ORM like [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907.aspx). Using an ORM you don't have to build your own queries, and allows you to use strong typed classes to "talk" to your database.

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM employee_table WHERE imployeeId IN (@ids)";
var ids = String.Join("," 
                MyCheckBoxList.Items
                    .Cast<ListItem>()
                    .Where(x => x.Selected)
                    .Select(x => x.Value);

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using(var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection)
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("ids", ids);
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            //get all the needed data from the reader
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey floros, thanks for your reply. I am just wondering what is (@ids) is it one of the columns in my db or do I need to define it somewhere

Comment: @DragonBorn it's the name of the parameter used by the SqlQuery, it will be replaced with the data when `command.Parameters.Add("ids", ids);` is called. See [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info abou the parameters. It helps you to prevent SQL injection.